# Selenium Grid in Java: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

I've wanted to write a Selenium Grid app in Java.

On http://localhost:4444/grid/console it says that the node is connected to the hub.

On the client-side I've wanted to write the following:

```
try {
        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://IP of Hub:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
        capability.setBrowserName("firefox");
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");

} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.err.println("URL Exception: "+ex.getMessage());
}
```

Unfortunately, the following exception was thrown when running the client app:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
...
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide geckodriver path before initializing a webdriver instance,

```
try {
     DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
     System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/PATH_OF_DRIVER/geckodriver.exe");
     driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://Hub_IP/wd/hub"), capability);
     capability.setBrowserName("firefox");
     driver.get("https://www.google.com");

} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
     System.err.println("URL Exception: "+ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: It still throws exactly the same exception.

Comment: I also tried to set the path variable on the node with: chmod u+x geckodriver AND
export PATH=$PATH:/PATH_OF_GECKO/geckodriver

Comment: Can you also make sure non root user has executable permission to access geckdriver?

Comment: The permissions are: -rwxrwxrwx

Answer (score 0):

Solution: There was something wrong with the geckodriver in Linux (node).
I added a node on a Windows PC and it worked.